# Drag and drop of an image in a web page using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, outsystems

I have list of thumbnails. I want to drag those images to the container. I want thumbnails to be changed to original pictures which are stored in the db.And I want to perform drag action (overlap)on those images which are dropped inside the container.

Below is the code snippet
Here i am using dragging function to send thumbnails

```
 "<script>
$(function() {
    $('#" + EncodeJavaScript(DraggableId) + "' ).draggable({
    helper: 'clone'

    });

});              
</script>"
```

Below is the code snippet where i am displaying the corresponding image

```
"<script>
$(function() {
    $('#" + EncodeJavaScript(DroppableId) + "' ).droppable({
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
           $( this ) this )

              .html('<img 
src=data:image/.png;base64,"+BinaryImg+" height=80px width=80px > ') '-> Here i am not getting actual image instead i got a blank image 
}
    });
});
</script>"
```

Comment: lost: question to this post,for those who find the question please append it to this post, thank you :)

Comment: @madalinivascu Hi 
I didn't get your query, can you sapless come back

Comment: @KarthikPB I think you need to phrase the question better so people know exactly what to reply to. Right now it's just your general objective and two js snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Outsystems doesn't store binary data as a base64 string. However there is a plugin available that can do conversions for base64. Generate a Base64 string out of your binary using the `BinaryToBase64` Action and use this output instead of your local `BinaryImg`.

https://www.outsystems.com/forge/Component_Details.aspx?ProjectId=287

Also I think you have to change `data:image/.png;base64` to `data:image/png;base64` though I'm not sure.